# Get FileTransfer upload options variables in php

Tags: javascript, php, cordova, file-upload

I'm using the cordovaFileTransfer plugin.
With the code below I also send options variable to my upload.php file.

```
var options = {
   fileKey: "file",
   channel: $scope.channel,
   fileName: $scope.filename ,
   chunkedMode: false,
   mimeType: "image/jpg"
};

$cordovaFileTransfer.upload(server, filePath, options).then(function(result) {
...
```

How can I retrieve the "channel" value (in the options variable) from within my php file.
In my php file I tried `$channel = $_POST["channel"];` but this is not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no channel option, you can't add options that don't exist.

To pass values to the server you have to use the params option:

```
var parameters = {};
parameters.channel = $scope.channel;

var options = {
   fileKey: "file",
   channel: $scope.channel,
   fileName: $scope.filename ,
   chunkedMode: false,
   mimeType: "image/jpg",
   params : parameters 
};
```

Now, you should be able to get the chanel param with `$_POST["channel"]`